# Reading and printing one char at a time - getche() and backspace in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, character, backspace, getch

I want to create typing training program. I need a function which immediately both reads and prints each character user hits - something like getche()

I have tried using getche from [this module](https://pypi.org/project/getch/) but it doesn't deal well with backspaces. When I hit backspace it prints ^? to the console and I want it to delete characters.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://pypi.org/project/getch/) are pretty clear.

> tried using getche

Don't do that, as `getche()` is documented to have the behavior that you say you don't want.

Call `getch()`, and assume responsibility for "echoing" or otherwise maintaining the display according to your requirements.

For example, this code accomplishes what you want:

```
from getch import getch


def pr(s):
    print(s, end='', flush=True)


def get_word():
    DELETE = 127  # ASCII code
    word = ''
    c = ''
    while not c.isspace():
        c = getch()
        if ord(c) == DELETE:
            pr('\r' + ' ' * len(word) + '\r')
            word = word[:-1]
            pr(word)
        if c.isprintable():
            word += c
            pr(c)
    print('\n')
    return word
```

Answer (score 1):

From the official [curses documentation page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) it's definition is:

> The curses module provides an interface to the curses library, the de-facto standard for portable advanced terminal handling.

You said you wanted to write a *typing training program*, well I think the best solution is to use the `curses` library for such task.

On UNIX systems it comes with the default installation of python, and if you are targeting windows systems I have found [windows-curses](https://pypi.org/project/windows-curses/) to add support greatly.

Basically you can find a HOWTO guide in [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) page from the **official docs**.

#### Here's an example usage the creates a textbox widget

The [curses.textpad](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#module-curses.textpad) module should be very useful for you.

```py
import curses
from curses import wrapper
from curses.textpad import Textbox, rectangle

def main(stdscr):   
    stdscr.addstr(0, 0, "Enter IM message: (hit Ctrl-G to send)")

    editwin = curses.newwin(5,30, 2,1)
    rectangle(stdscr, 1,0, 1+5+1, 1+30+1)
    stdscr.refresh()

    box = Textbox(editwin)

    # Let the user edit until Ctrl-G is struck.
    box.edit()

    # Get resulting contents
    message = box.gather()
    print(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wrapper(main)
```

#### Here's what it looks like using the `windows-curses` module

[image: Curses example screenshot]

You can do many things using this library, I suggest you go on and read the docs on the links I have provided.